# Center(x and y) svg element between two circles on a diagonal line with javascript

Tags: javascript, math, svg, position, jsdom

I already researched **A LOT** about this.

[EXAMPLE 1]

When the objects are straight, I can position it in the center without major problems, using the formula:

- targetX: (Circle3X + Circle7X) / 2 - (targetWidth / 2);
- targetY: (Circle3Y + Circle7Y) / 2 - (targetHeight / 2)

Then getting:

`rectSvg.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + targetX + "," + targetY + ")")`

[EXAMPLE 2]

The problem occurs when the circle elements are on the diagonal line, where the rect element that I need to position needs to be rotated accordingly. Using same formula above, the rect element never stay exacty on center between circles (it looks like it's in the center but it's not). The transform attr in this case:

`rectSvg.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + targetX + "," + targetY + ") rotate(6.2)");`

[IMAGES EXAMPLE 1 AND EXAMPLE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHFMh.png)

For God's sake, who can help me position this element in the center diagonally?

Note: I'm generating svg on the server (jsdom lib on node.js) so I do not have client methods like: getBoundingClientRects, getBBox and so on

Thank you very much for your attention.

Snippet of code of calculation X and Y of circles

`var circle3X = dom.window.document.getElementById('circle3').getAttribute("cx");
var circle3Y = dom.window.document.getElementById('circle3').getAttribute("cy");`


`var circle7X = dom.window.document.getElementById('circle7').getAttribute("cx");
var circle7Y = dom.window.document.getElementById('circle7').getAttribute("cy");`


`var centerX = (circle3X + circle7X) / 2 - (rectWidth / 2);
var centerY = (circle3Y + circle7Y) / 2 - (rectHeight / 2);`

`rectSvg.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + centerX+ "," + centerY + ") rotate(16.3)");`

Comment: Can you please provide your existing code in a snippet?

Comment: Hi kfedorov91! The question has been edited as you requested.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] If we have to do a lot of work to recreate your problem, you are much less likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, objects like `circle3` are described with axis-aligned rectangle, but desired result looks like inclined rectangle.

To find center of that rectangle properly, you can just use centers of source rectangles instead of left top corners.

```
center1x = top1.x + width1 / 2
center2x = top1.x + height1 / 2
result_center.x = (center1x + center2x) / 2
and similar for y-coordinate
```

And to get coordinates of the corners of inclined rectangle:

```
 dist = sqrt((center2y - center1y)^2 + (center2x - center1x)^2)
 ssin = (center2y - center1y) / dist
 ccos = (center2x - center1x) / dist

 corner.x = result_center.x +/- result_width/2 * ccos +/- result_height/2 * ssin
 corner.y = result_center.y -/+ result_width/2 * ssin +/- result_height/2 * ccos
```

Ddifferent combinations of + and - signs on the first expression give 4 corners. Signs in the second expression should be changed correspondingly (so valid combinations are `++-+, +---, -+++, --+-`)